# PHP XML parser making keys as capitalized

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML -

```
<SimpleData>Some data</SimpleData>
```

I'm converting the above XML to array using -

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $array);
xml_parser_free($p);
print_r ($array);
```

I get this output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => SIMPLEDATA
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 1
            [value] => Some data
        )

)
```

The problem is that **[tag]** gives the values as **SIMPLEDATA**. But I don't want it to be capitalized. 
It should be the same as it is in the XML.

How to correct it ?

Comment: This is the really old SAX style parser. I suggest reading about the newer XMLReader and DOM APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable case folding just after creating the parser:

```
$p = xml_parser_create();

xml_parser_set_option($p, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); // <-- disable case folding

xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $array);
xml_parser_free($p);

print_r ($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag] => SimpleData
            [type] => complete
            [level] => 1
            [value] => Some data
        )

)
```